# Change height of div on click with jquery

Tags: jquery, height, jquery-animate

I'm trying to expand the height of a div element with the following code:

html:

```
<div id="expandbtn">more..</div>

<div id="portfolio"><div class="itemweb" title="lol" rel="#derp"><div class="thumb"><img src="images/items/skills.jpg" title="Skills" rel="#derp"/></div>
```

script:

```
$('#expandbtn').click(function(){
$('#portfolio').animate({height:'72px'}, 500);});
```

css:

```
#portfolio {
width:914px;
height:295px;
margin:0 0 0 -8px;
overflow:hidden;}
```

But it won't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: from original height (295px) to 72px it means you're contracting it :) .. btw, your code seems fine.. maybe u can't see anything because there is no background on portfolio div

Comment: works for me, check this:  http://jsfiddle.net/TrDtc/4/

Comment: I just pasted the script below the content just before </body> tag and that worked!

Comment: It works fine for me apart from a rather embarrassing moment where I hadn't set jsfiddle to jQuery. Deleted my 'answer' as it wasn't really one.

Answer (score 33):

your code is just fine. you can also try

```
$('#portfolio').css("height","74px");
```

try putting some backgroung color or image to visualize clearly

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/49HQM/4/

Answer (score 5):

Try toload it when the document is ready:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#expandbtn').click(function(){
      $('#portfolio').animate({height:'72px'}, 500);
   });
```

Comment: Nice touch with the animation

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, but try setting position and a background color to see the element, like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/49HQM/1/).

Also, it will not animate the height of the elements inside the portfolio div, if that is what you are trying to do (unless size of those elements are in percent)?